# How can I solve the linear recurrence problem $f(n)=f(n-1)+3 \cdot f(n-3)+2n$ using matrix exponentiation when $ f(1)$ , $f(2)$ and $f(3)$ are given.

Tags: linear-algebra

The porblem is $f(n)=f(n-1)+3f(n-3)+2n$. I solved $f(n)=f(n-1)+3f(n-3)$ and adding summation of $2n$ upto $n$. But this is wrong. It requires too much of pre calculation.
I tried this problem based on the concept as given here https://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/recurrence-relation-and-matrix-exponentiation/

Comment: 1) The second sentence in your title is not understandable. 2) If you mention "using matrix", it means that you have had already exercises on this subject. What method is advised there ? 3) You do not mention initial conditions $f(1),f(2),f(3)$ ? What are they ? Arbitrary constants ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's taken from a live coding competition, the NIT codathon.

Comment: This problem has shown up a lot lately, see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078554/need-help-in-the-recurrence-relation?noredirect=1#comment6346964_3078554).  Nobody should respond to it until the competition has ended.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_n$ be the vector
$$ v_n=\begin{pmatrix}1\\n\\f(n)\\f(n-1)\\f(n-2)\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then apparently we can compute $v_n$ from $v_{n-1}$
by a matrix multiplication:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1\\n\\f(n)\\f(n-1)\\f(n-2)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0\\
0&2&1&0&3\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\n-1\\f(n-1)\\f(n-2)\\f(n-3)\end{pmatrix}.$$

---

Nevertheless, you might be able to proceed faster if you consider $g(n):=f(n)+an+b$ for suitable constants $a,b$. We find the recurrence relation
$$\begin{align}g(n)&=f(n)+an+b\\
&=f(n-1)+3f(n-3)+2n+an+b\\
&=g(n-1)-a(n-1)-b+3g(n-3)-3a(n-3)-3b+2n+an+b\\
&=g(n-1)+3g(n-3)+(2-3a)n+(10a-3b)\end{align}$$
and this looks particularly nice if you pick $a,b$ such that $2-3a=10a-3b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $g(n):=f(n)+an+b$ for constants $a,\,b$ we'll choose later so $g(n)=g(n-1)+3g(n-3)+(2-3a)n+10a-3b$ (you should double-check my arithmetic). With $a=2/3,\,b=10a/3=20/9$ this simplifies to $g(n)=g(n-1)+g(n-3)$, which you already know how to solve. Then $f(n)=g(n)-an-b$.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks to read
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  f(1) = a \hfill \cr 
  f(2) = b \hfill \cr 
  f(3) = c \hfill \cr 
  f(n) = f(n - 1) + 3f(n - 3) + 2n\quad \left| {\;4 \le n} \right. \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
that is
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(n) - f(n - 1) - 3f(n - 3) =   \cr 
  &  + 2n\left[ {4 \le n} \right] + a\left[ {1 = n} \right] + b\left[ {2 = n} \right] + c\left[ {3 = n} \right] \cr} 
$$
where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$$
\left[ P \right] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {P = TRUE}  \\
   0 & {P = FALSE}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$

If you want to use the matrix notation, then
indicating with $\bf E$ the [shift matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix)
$$
{\bf E} = \left( {\matrix{
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots   \cr 
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots   \cr 
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots   \cr 
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  \cdots   \cr 
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \ddots   \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
then the equation is
$$
\left( {{\bf I} - {\bf E} - 3\,{\bf E}^{\,{\bf 3}} } \right){\bf f} = {\bf v} = \left( {a,b,c,8,10, \cdots } \right)^T 
$$
which gives
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf f} = {{\bf I} \over {{\bf I} - {\bf E} - 3\,{\bf E}^{\,{\bf 3}} }}{\bf v} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{\bf E}^{\,{\bf n}} \left( {{\bf I}
 + \sqrt 3 \,{\bf E}} \right)^{\,{\bf n}} \left( {{\bf I} - \sqrt 3 \,{\bf E}} \right)^{\,{\bf n}} } } \right){\bf v} =   \cr 
  &  = \quad  \cdots  \cr} 
$$